# Creating Files on Top of Pre-Existing Ones

Tags: java, file, io

```
    File file = new File ("A" + File.separator + "B.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

The block above creates a directory entitled "A" and a *file (as opposed to directory)* entitled "B.txt".

---

While playing around, I had originally made a directory entitled "A" and a subdirectory of "A" entitled "B.txt". By running the code block, I created a directory hierarchy A --> B.txt. I realized my mistake, and changed this former, incorrect block to the one posted above.

When I ran the correct block, above, however, `FileOutputStream out` threw a `FileNotFoundException`. This suggests that, with the directory hierarchy A --> B.txt in place, java refused to create another hierarchy that placed "B.txt" **the file** under the directory "A".

Why is this?

Comment: show us the output...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Java documentation for the `createNewFile` method you will see why this exception is raised.

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile())

According to your question the file "B.txt" already exists in your "A" directory. That's the reason the exception is raised.

Comment: But the existing "B.txt" is an existing directory and not an existing FILE. Shouldn't createNewFile create a new file then?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to do with the above code block. Could you be a bit clearer about what the output of the program is and what you would have expected it to be (which directories, files do you currently have and which directories, files do you want to have) ? I suppose Java don't wanna make the new file because it has exactly the same name (and path) as an already existing directory. Using the path ".../A/B.txt" how can the file system know if we want the directory or the file?

Comment: Delete the (wrong) directory "B.txt" and try the above code again, I think it should work.